# Javascript - Add HTML with UserScripts

Tags: javascript, html, userscripts, tampermonkey, getelementsbyclassname

I'm new with Javascrip and UserScripts and I need your help 'cause i'm stuck with something...

Basicly, I'm trying to **add others buttons** by a **client-side way** to a response-field in a forum.
See pictures of [how it actually looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zS9O.png) and [how I want it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiveT.png)...

I'm using for this **TamperMonkey UserScripts** and **Javascript functions**.

I know I have to use

```
document.getElementsByClassName();
```

and

```
x[0].innerHTML = something;
```

The problem is that each button is a member of a list and has it's own Class. It's style is also defined by the class.

Below, the code of one of the buttons...

`<li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton16 preview"><a href="" title="Preview">Preview</a></li>`

I thought I simply could get the HTML code of the last button of the list with the *getElements* function, add other HTML code for the new button at the end of the 1st element of the array returned by *getElements* and render it it on the browser with *.innerHTML*.
But unfortunately **it didn't work** and I don't understand why...

My code should looks like this

```js
myfunction() {
    var ReturnedCode;
    var NewButtonHTMLCode = '<li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton17 NewButton"><a href="" title="NewButtonAction">NewButton</a></li>';
    ReturnedCode = document.getElementsByClassName("markItUpButton markItUpButton16 preview").join;
    var FinalCode = ReturnedCode + NewButtonHTMLCode;
    document.getElementsByClassName("markItUpButton markItUpButton16 preview").innerHTML[0] = FinalCode;
}
```

```html
<div class="markItUpContainer">
  <div class="markItUpHeader">
    <ul>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton1 ">
        <a href="" accesskey="B" title="Bold [Ctrl+B]">Bold</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton2 ">
        <a href="" accesskey="I" title="Italic [Ctrl+I]">Italic</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton3 ">
        <a href="" accesskey="U" title="Underline [Ctrl+U]">Underline</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton4 ">
        <a href="" accesskey="S" title="Stroke [Ctrl+S]">Stroke</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpSeparator">---------------</li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton5 ">
        <a href="" accesskey="P" title="Picture [Ctrl+P]">Picture</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton6 ">
        <a href="" accesskey="L" title="Link [Ctrl+L]">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpSeparator">---------------</li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton7  markItUpDropMenu">
        <a href="" accesskey="S" title="Size [Ctrl+S]">Size</a>
        <ul>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton7-1 ">
            <a href="" title="Big">Big</a>
          </li>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton7-2 ">
            <a href="" title="Small">Small</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpSeparator">---------------</li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton8 ">
        <a href="" title="Bulleted list">Bulleted list</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton9 ">
        <a href="" title="Numeric list">Numeric list</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton10 ">
        <a href="" title="List item">List item</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpSeparator">---------------</li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton11 ">
        <a href="" title="Quotes">Quotes</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12  markItUpDropMenu">
        <a href="" title="Smiles">Smiles</a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12-1 ">
            <a href="" title="Smile">Smile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12-2 ">
            <a href="" title="Neutral">Neutral</a>
          </li>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12-3 ">
            <a href="" title="Sad">Sad</a>
          </li>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12-4 ">
            <a href="" title="Big smile">Big smile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12-5 ">
            <a href="" title="Yikes">Yikes</a>
          </li>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12-6 ">
            <a href="" title="Wink">Wink</a>
          </li>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12-7 ">
            <a href="" title="Hmm">Hmm</a>
          </li>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12-8 ">
            <a href="" title="Tongue">Tongue</a>
          </li>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12-9 ">
            <a href="" title="Lol">Lol</a>
          </li>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12-10 ">
            <a href="" title="Mad">Mad</a>
          </li>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12-11 ">
            <a href="" title="Roll">Roll</a>
          </li>
          <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton12-12 ">
            <a href="" title="Cool">Cool</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpSeparator">---------------</li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton13 browser-os-button">
        <a href="" title="Paste browser / operating system versions">Paste browser / operating system versions</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpSeparator">---------------</li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton14 scratchblocks-button markItUpDropMenu">
        <a href="" title="Scratchblocks">Scratchblocks</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpSeparator">---------------</li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton15 clean">
        <a href="" title="Clean">Clean</a>
      </li>
      <li class="markItUpButton markItUpButton16 preview">
        <a href="" title="Preview">Preview</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <textarea class="markup markItUpEditor" cols="95" id="id_body" name="body" rows="20"></textarea>
  <div class="markItUpFooter">
    <div class="markItUpResizeHandle"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myfunction()
</script>
```

Can anyone help me?
Even if the mistake is obvious for you, it isn't for me...
Thank you.

Comment: *NewButtonHTMLCode = "<li class="markItUpButton* syntax error...

Comment: *ReturnedCode.[0]* second syntax error

Comment: And a NodeList hasnt an innerHTML property

Comment: You should read trough many many js tutorials, youve got many many mistakes...

Answer (score 0):

```
 window.onload= function() {    

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("markItUpButton"),el=>el.innerHTML+=" added");
};
```

Your code wont work in any way. So you may wait for the page to load, then iterate over all elements and append sth to innerhtml ( += ) ...

Comment: I don't think I need to wait the page fully loads because TamperMonkey's scripts only run when the page is loaded, isn't it? Also, I already tryed to change HTML code and it worked ^-^ Now i 'd like to know how to add code...